# set value of observed variable

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, shared-memory

This question is rather about concept than a particular language. I have some "variable" and some handlers - functions which are to be called when value of this variable is changed. It is implemented in javascript, but it is not important. Several handlers can be watching value of the same variable and are called in same order they were registered as watchers. What should I do when in one of this handlers is value changed? I'm thinking about these aproaches:

1. value cannot be changed in the "onChange" handler - same approach is known from triggers in MySQL for example. But it is uncomfortable and to limiting.
2. value is changed asynchronously - all handlers are called, then after the "next tick" is value changed and all handlers are called again. It could work, (I know I need care about infinite loop ). Disadvantage of this approach is that all handlers are called twice and this can have negative impact on performance (blinking UI etc)
3. value is changed synchronously - handlers queue processing is stopped when value is changed in one handler and then are handlers queue processed from begining again. Advantage - not all handlers are called twice. Disadvantage - registration order matters.

Comment: There is no algorithm in this question. Your question might be better suited for Programmers anyway.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I see three algorithms in this question. Where is the problem?

Comment: @macmoonshine They are sets of assumptions and constraints, not algorithms.

Comment: @BartoszKP when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Sorry, I've misread your comment previously. Good point, although the main point was that there is a better place for this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to implement two kind of handlers: Pre- and post- assignment handlers. Only the pre-assignment handlers are allowed to change the value, and if a pre-handler changes the variable without re-triggering of the handlers. In your case you define all handlers which could change the value as pre-assignment handlers, and the others as post-assignment.

With this approach every handler is just called once.

Comment: nice and clear division of resposibility. I like it.